# Air Compressors never have air pressure gauges here so what is the easiest way to achieve a certain tire pressure?

Tags: tire-pressure, japan

I just checked a high end bicycle shop and it doesn't have air pressure gauge on the air compressor outlet( or anywhere) and the local shop doesn't have one at the end of long outside one- it is doubtful any bicycle shop has one. They also don't sell bicycle pressure gauges. It is against their religion or something to ensure the bicycles achieve a certain tire pressure- standard is all you get. I can buy air pressure gauges online but I do overpressure them leak it back or are there a air pressure controlling intermediate valve?

Comment: What air pressure level are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I’d just buy a floor pump with pressure gauge. If the bike shop’s compressor inflates to a high (but still safe) pressure you could get an air pressure gauge (e.g. LifeLine’s digital pressure gauge or Topeak SmartGauge D2) which displays tyre pressure and has an air release button.

Comment: I don't know about your shop, but it's not uncommon to use compressors for initial inflation (perhaps to thumb-firm on a road bike) then finish off with a pump.  A major reason for having a compressor at all is seating tubeless tyres.  Anyway the bike shop won't know what pressure you want to run at for your weight and the terrain

Comment: The commonly used Park Tool inflator has a gauge. Interesting to see they aren’t using one that has a gauge.

Comment: In a rare exception, the hand pump at a rather upscale bicycle shop had a pressure gauge. Shop purchased hand or foot pumps don't have pressure gauges.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to get a specific tire pressure is to carry your own air gauge.
Through experience you can develop a feel for how much pressure is in the tire by squeezing and then dial in the exact pressure with your gauge.

1. Put air in the tire until it seems to be about 75% full
2. Check it with the gauge
3. Put in a little more air
4. Repeat step 2 and 3 until it's dialed in
5. If you put in too much let it out in short bursts - check it with the gauge after each burst.

After you build some experience it goes pretty fast.

It would be nice if all public tire air supplies had a gauge. The few I've used were inaccurate so I don't trust other people's gauges. Get your own gauge - don't get a cheap one.

For home it is possible to get a floor pump with an accurate gauge built in.

Comment: +1: Your own gauge does not need to be particularly accurate, as long as it is consistent. Digital gauges will be both, all but the cheapest mechanical ones are usually consistent.

Comment: @mattnz It seems like accuracy is important as well as consistency. I don't want a gauge that is always reading 10 lbs too low or too high.